# How to use CHECKSUM in a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create my own logic for tables synchronization in SQL Server Express 2019. I was hoping that such simple task would work:

1. Have a `Customers` table
2. Have a `Synchronization` table

   ```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Synchronization]
    (
        [PK] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [TableName] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [RecordPK] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [RecordChecksum] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RecordDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [RecordIsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL
    )
   ```
3. Have a trigger on `Customers`:

   ```
    CREATE TRIGGER trgCustomers_INSERT 
    ON Customers 
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
        INSERT INTO Synchronization(PK, TableName, RecordPK, RecordChecksum,
                                    RecordDate, RecordIsDeleted)
        VALUES (NEWID(), 'Customers',
                (SELECT PK FROM inserted),
                (SELECT CHECKSUM(*) FROM inserted),
                GETDATE(), 0)
   ```

... but I got an error about the `SELECT CHECKSUM(*) FROM inserted` part:

> Cannot use CHECKSUM(*) in a computed column, constraint, default definition, or INSERT statement.

Is there any other way to add new `Customer`'s CHECKSUM or some hash to the `Synchronization` table?

Comment: Be very wary when using `CHECKSUM` for anything that's not just speeding up index seeks. The algorithm it uses has very bad failure cases with collisions that mean that it's very easy to get different rows with identical checksums, even more so than you'd expect by chance alone. (`BINARY_CHECKSUM` is marginally better, if not by much.) Storing `CHECKSUM(*)` makes things worse, as changing the table structure results in all previously calculated checksums (silently) becoming invalid. Consider at least writing out the columns.

Comment: You suffer the most common mistake in triggers - assuming a single row is affected by the insert statement. Where is the PK for your sync table? And why do you need a GUID in that table?

Comment: @SMor My app will insert records  only one per time ... but I have a trigger for UPDATE too, using same logic. And there can be bulk updates. Should I consider the UPDATE trigger unreliable as well?

Comment: @AlexeyTitov as it stands you should *not* use the answer you have marked as the solution. Like your trigger, it assumes that DML statements can't effect more than 1 row. That isn't simply not true. [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: @Larnu got it, thanks

Comment: @Larnu I updated the answer to reflect the feedback that was provided. Do you still see any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `VALUES` syntax when inserting and you won't get an error using `CHECKSUM` while inserting.

**Example:**

```
declare @t table (val int)

-- works
insert into @t select checksum(*) from ( select ID from (select 1 as ID union select 2) b ) a

-- reproduce error
insert into @t
values
((select top 1 checksum(*) C from ( select ID from (select 1 as ID union select 2) b ) a))
```

**Implementing the concept in your trigger:**

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trgCustomers_INSERT 
 ON Customers 
 AFTER INSERT
 AS
 begin
     INSERT INTO Synchronization(PK, TableName, RecordPK, RecordChecksum,
                                 RecordDate, RecordIsDeleted)

     select NEWID() as PK, 
     'Customers' as TableName,
             PK as RecordPK,
             checksum(*) as RecordChecksum,
             GETDATE() as RecordDate, 
             0 as RecordIsDeleted
     from inserted
     
 end
```

Comment: This approach is fatally flawed as it assumes only one row is ever inserted at a time. `inserted` can contain any number of rows; this will use the checksum of one row non-deterministically. Of course this problem is already present in the original question, but still.

Comment: This will actually error when the the DML operation has more than 1 roe, @JeroenMostert . Better than quietly not doing the right thing, but still fatally flawed.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert 95% of the SQL came from the OP I just changed how to make the `checksum` available to insert. Agreed, the trigger can be written better.

Comment: The question didn't mention accounting for multiple rows. If you see a better answer can you guys please post it? I was just trying to solve for making `checksum` available in the insert statement.

Comment: Just because the OP's question contains fatally flawed code doesn't meant that the answers should. Part of writing a *good* answer is fixing the errors in the OP's code. That includes those that include known behaviour flaws (like here) and things like security flaws (like injection).

Comment: @Larnu I agree there is a lot of room for improve. For example `RecordIsDeleted` is hard coded to 0. Logic could be written figure that out instead of hard coding 0. And so on and so on. If the question is updated about how to handle multiple values or fixing `RecordsIsDeleted` I can change the answer.

Comment: The question doesn't *need* to be updated to handle multi rows, @vvvv4d ... The trigger **must**; that isn't a point for debate that's a fact. This trigger *will* cause an error if more than one row is effected and that makes it a bad solution. Especially as so many users get confused by a "subquery returned more than 1 row" errors on a query like `INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE2;`

Comment: @Larnu I've updated the answer to account for multiple values.

Comment: No! A `WHILE`  is going to tank performance here! `Inserted` is a psuedo-table, treat it like a table.. have a read of the article I linked under the question, as it seems you too need to understand how to properly write set based triggers.

Comment: @Larnu updated to be set based. The issue was with the `VALUES` syntax being used while inserting.